# TypeError: book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'book_id'

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I'm writing a program to give details of book to user after a search. Running the program I encounter this TypeError: book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'book_id'. I do not know where to supply the required argument again. Please I need help on this. Here is the code.

PS: I am new to flask and python, only learning.

```
@app.route("/book/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/book/<book_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
#@loggedin_required
def book(book_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        activeUser = session["user_id"]
       
        book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=:book_id", {"book_id":book_id}).fetchone()
       
        check = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user_id=:user_id AND book_id = :book_id", {"user_id":user_id, "book_id":book_id})
        if check > 0:
            flash("You have left a review for this book already!")
            return redirect("/book/" + isbn)
        else:
            rating_result = int(rating_result)

            rating_result = request.form.get("rating_result")
            comments = request.form.get("comments")
            db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (rating_result, comments, book_id, user_id) VALUES \
                            (:rating_result, :comments, :book_id, :user_id)",
                            {"rating_result":rating_result, "comments":comments, "book_id":book_id, "user_id":user_id})
            db.commit()
            flash("Review recieved. Thank you!")
            return redirect("/book/" + isbn)
        return render_template("book.html", book=book, book_id=book_id, comments=comments, user_id=activeUser)
```

Comment: You used the name `book` twice.

Comment: What is `/book/` supposed to do? Your function is written under the assumption that it receives a book ID from the request. You can give `book_id`  a default value, but it's not clear what that default value should be.

Comment: This function has two routes associated with it - one that supplies the `book_id` parameter, and one that doesn't.  The only way that could work is if the parameter was optional - `def book(book_id=None):` perhaps.  But that's going to require further changes, as the code currently expects there to be a valid book ID.  You might want to split the routes between two different functions, and render a book index or something like that in the one handling the `/book/` route.